# Not getting updated zoom level after extent is set? (ArcGIS JavaScript API)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, zoom

There is a function in my map that works very nicely for zooming to a polygon (parcel) that has been selected:

```
_zoomToParcel: function(parcel) {
  this.map.setExtent(parcel.geometry.getExtent().expand(1.5));
}
```

The end user has requested that the zoom level be restricted to no more than 18. If it's a very small parcel, the zoom level may be 19 or 20, and then they have to zoom back out to find enough surroundings to orient themselves. Fair enough. I thought this would be as simple as adding in a get/set zoom:

```
_zoomToParcel: function(parcel) {
  this.map.setExtent(parcel.geometry.getExtent().expand(1.5));
  if (this.map.getZoom() > 18) {
    this.map.setZoom(18);
  }
}
```

However, this appears to be getting the zoom level from *before* the application resets the extent to the parcel. When I console.log the results of `this.map.getZoom()`, it tells me the initial zoom level (5), not the new zoom level (20) after the extent is reset. Running that function if the map starts off very zoomed-in (e.g. 20) will zoom it back out to 18, meaning the get/set logic works — I'm just not getting the "right" zoom.

How can I catch whether the map has zoomed in too far?

Answer (score 4):

Try waiting for the `extent-change` event to fire.

http://jsbin.com/sapuxelepa/edit?html,output

```
  var map;

  require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "topo",  
      center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
      zoom: 13
    });
    var extentListener = map.on("extent-change",function(evt)
      {
        console.log("extent change",evt.lod);
        if(evt.lod.level > 13)
          map.setZoom(13);


        extentListener.remove();
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: This should work, as long as I can have it only watching for the extent change within that function (in regular pan/zoom operation, they want to be able to go in > 18). At minimum, this gives me a good direction to research.

Answer (score 2):

@Kirk's answer works and is simple, but I didn't like that it would zoom all the way in and then zoom out a little.

The method I can up with is to find the map extent at the smallest scale and compare that to my extent. If my extent is larger, then I can safely zoom to extent. If my extent is smaller, then I zoom to whatever zoom level desired.

```
...

    const buffer = 1.05;
    const isGraphicsOverflowMinMapExtent = await this.isGraphicsOverflowMinMapExtent(
      map,
      graphics,
      buffer,
    );

    if (isGraphicsOverflowMinMapExtent) {
      map.setExtent(graphicsExtent);
      return;
    } else {
      map.centerAndZoom(graphicsCenterPoint, DEFAULT_ZOOM_LEVEL);
    }

...
```

```
  /**
   *Determines if the extents of an array of graphics is larger than the map extent at the max
   *scale returns true if the graphics are larger than the map extent. A buffer is used to
   *avoid graphics from being split
   *@returns True if the graphics extent is larger than the minimum map extent; otherwise, false
   */
  public async isGraphicsOverflowMinMapExtent(
    map: any,
    graphics: any[],
    buffer: number,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
      require([
        'esri/graphicsUtils',
        'esri/geometry/scaleUtils',
        'esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils',
        'esri/geometry/Extent',
        'esri/SpatialReference',
      ], ([graphicsUtils, scaleUtils, webMercatorUtils, Extent, SpatialReference] => {
        const graphicsExtent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(graphics);

        const mapExtentAtMinScale = scaleUtils
          .getExtentForScale(map, map.getMaxScale())
          .setSpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 });

        const [minXmin, minYmin] = webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(
          mapExtentAtMinScale.xmin,
          mapExtentAtMinScale.ymin,
        );

        const [minXmax, minYmax] = webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(
          mapExtentAtMinScale.xmax,
          mapExtentAtMinScale.ymax,
        );

        const minDeltaX = Math.abs(minXmax - minXmin) * buffer;
        const minDeltaY = Math.abs(minYmax - minYmin) * buffer;

        return graphicsExtent.getHeight() > minDeltaY || graphicsExtent.getWidth() > minDeltaX;
      });
  }
```